Souls originating from Adam HaRishon
In the Zohar ( Zohar/Bereshit B/Chapter 62 ), it says:
358. In the words, "This is the book of the generations of Adam" (Beresheet 5:1), "GENERATIONS" REFERS to images OF THE SOULS, BECAUSE ALL THE SOULS WHO ORIGINATED FROM ADAM ARE LISTED IN THE BOOK. Rabbi Yitzchak said: The Holy One, blessed be He, revealed to Adam the images OF THE SOULS of all the generations who will come into the world and of all the sages and kings of the world destined to rule over Yisrael.
Why does the Lashon say, 'ALL THE SOULS WHO ORIGINATED FROM ADAM ARE LISTED IN THE BOOK'. Doesn't everyone human being come from Adam HaRishon?
The phrase is talking as if there exist souls that did not originate from Adam HaRishon.
https://www.zohar.com/zohar/Bereshit%20B/chapters/62

Your question isn't on the Zohar, but on the translator's commentary. The bits that are in CAPS are not translations, but commentaries. Can't figure out  from that site who translated it. Do you know? For all I know, it's a Christian site

Why would a goy got out their way a make an entire site with word to word translation?

I don't know, same reason, I imagine, that a Christian association published a full translation of Pardes Rimonim? Even if it's a Jew, even a God fearing one, I wouldn't trust his commentary without at least knowing who it is!

Despite the fact that we don't know who said this, it is indeed true that there are souls that do not originate from Adam Harishon. This is explained in Shaar HaGilgulim, Chapter 7:

קצת נשמות יש, שלא באו כלולות בנשמת אדה"ר כשנברא, ואלו נקראים נשמות
חדשות באמת לגמרי. אבל כל הנשמות אשר כבר באו כלולות בנשמת אדה"ר, הם
הנקראים נשמות ישנות,
there are some souls that were not part of Adam's soul when it was
first created. These are truly completely "new souls", whereas the
souls that were already included in Adam are called "old souls"


Could you provide a few examples of those new souls? I’m talking about actual individuals. Are there any individuals that we know of who are purported to be “new souls”?

@YaacovDeane The Alter Rebbe was said to be a "new soul".

@shmosel So was the Ba’al Shem Tov. I would be curious if such a thing were ever said about the Ramchal. It wouldn’t surprise me. But how is such a statement disputed by anyone? And if the declaration is made, what are the practical implications for anyone else?
